# Finite difference method with variable coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, finite-differences, finite-element-method

I want to numerically solve the following elliptic PDE for both when $x \in [0,1]\times [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{align*}
-\text{div}(\kappa(x,y)\nabla u(x,y)) &= f(x,y), ~(x,y) \in (0,1)\times(0,1)\\ 
u(x, 0) &= c, ~\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,y) = 0, ~\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,y) = h(0, y), ~\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,1) = 0, 
\end{align*}
using a finite difference method. When $\kappa$ is constant, this is easy, but I am not sure how to proceed in the case where $\kappa$ is a function. In addition, in this case, how should I incorporate these Neumann boundary conditions?

Comment: How is this an elliptic equation? You only have first order derivatives. Did you mean $\textrm{div} (k(x) \nabla u(x))$?

Comment: @PierreCarre Sorry for the typo, yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily apply standard finite differences. Just note that
$$
\textrm{div} (k \nabla u) = \nabla k \cdot \nabla u + k \Delta u = k\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\right) + \frac{\partial k}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial k}{\partial y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.
$$

Your equation on node $(i,j)$ would be

\begin{align*}
k_{ij}\left(\frac{u_{i+1,j}-2u_{i,j}+u_{i-1,j}}{h^2}+\frac{u_{i,j+1}-2u_{i,j}+u_{i,j-1}}{h^2}\right)+\\(k'_x)_{i,j}\frac{u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}}{2h}+(k'_y)_{i,j}\frac{u_{i,j+1}-u_{i,j-1}}{2h} = -f_{i,j}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Are we again taking the finite difference to estimate the derivative of $k$?

Comment: $k$ is a given function, in principle the partial derivatives of $k$ are to be computed analitically.

Comment: I am assuming that the $\kappa$ was only observed along the 2D grid without any analytical derivative information.

Comment: In that case, sure, you can estimate the derivatives of $\kappa$ also using finite differences.